# Calculating the Fibonacci Sequence using inline assembly in C

Tags: c, inline-assembly

I've tried to make a simple console program in C (using clang as the compiler) that would use inline assembly to calculate the Fibonacci's number with the index that's entered in the standard input.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int ulaz;
  scanf("%d",&ulaz);
  int rezultat;
  asm(
"mov %1,%%ecx\n"
".intel_syntax\n"
"mov eax,0\n"
"mov ebx,1\n"
"petlja:\n"
"add eax,ebx\n"
"xchg eax,ebx\n"
"loop petlja\n"
".att_syntax\n"
"mov %%ebx,%0\n"
: "=m" (rezultat)
: "m" (ulaz)
);
  printf("%d\n",rezultat);
  return 0;
}
```

It appears to calculate the Fibonacci's numbers, but not with the index the user has entered. For instance, for the input "10", it should output "55" (the 10th Fibonacci's number), but it outputs "89" (which is a Fibonacci's number, but not the 10th Fibonacci's number). Any idea where the error is?

Comment: Just know that there is absolutely no checking done by the compiler for anything you choose to include between `asm(...)` which can give you a false sense of security that you are getting no errors. (that is most likely due to the compiler completely ignoring the code, not the crisp logic and syntax between `asm(..` and `...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to move the count check to the beginning of the loop block rather than the end, that because you do the check at the end you go through the loop one more time than you want. Either that or dec ecx before entering the loop.

Moving the check to the begging would be something like (not checked, just illustrative):

```
"mov %1,%%ecx\n"
".intel_syntax\n"
"mov eax,0\n"
"mov ebx,1\n"
loop_start:\n"
"test ecx, ecx\n"
"jz loop_done"
"add eax,ebx\n"
"xchg eax,ebx\n"
"dec ecx\n"
"jmp loop_start\n"
"loop_done:\n"
".att_syntax\n"
"mov %%ebx,%0\n"
```